# How to remove a compiler option that python disutils includes (language code=pic32 not recognized)

Tags: python, gcc, solaris, distutils, msgpack

I'm trying to compile the msgpack-python python module with gcc (v4.7) on solaris 10. The python installed is 2.6.8. Distutils is automatically picking up a incorrect compiler option (-xcode=pic32) that I want to remove from command.

The full command that distutils is putting together is:

```
/opt/csw/bin/gcc-4.7 -DNDEBUG -O -O2 -pipe -mcpu=v9 -I/opt/csw/include -xcode=pic32 -I/opt/csw/include/python2.6 -c msgpack/_msgpack.c -o build/temp.solaris-2.10-sun4v-2.6/msgpack/_msgpack.o
```

but produces this error:

gcc-4.7: error: language code=pic32 not recognized

then fails. If I remove that -xcode=pic32 option and manually execute the above command the module compiles successfully.

I need to be able to do this in an automated fashion though (using a buildfarm to produce the packages). The question is, Without modifying or changing the current python or distutils, is there a way to "remove" this option that distutils is picking up, so I can have the python setup.py process build the module appropriately (i.e. without the pic32 option)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do not compile with that gcc. `-xcode=pic32` is Sun Studio complier command line parameter. It will lead to linking problems too, even if you compile OK. Compile with [SUN CoolTools](http://www.opensparc.net/cool-tools.html) `gcc` which can understand such parameter, or use [Oracle Solaris Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/overview/index.html) for SPARC.

Some hints:

1. GCC produce very slow code for SPARC, that's for why SUN created Cool Tools.
2. You haven't to remove `-xcode=pic32`, but change for `-m32 -fpic`, when you insist on gcc-4.7
3. To get mature setup of OSS tool I'm using [pkgsrc](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/software/packages.html) compiling with Studio Express to particular CPU (`-xtarget=native`)

Answer (score 0):

You may also find luck by setting the follow env vars:

```
export CC=$gcc_dir_path  # Example: /usr/bin/gcc
export CXX=$gxx_dir_path  # Example: /usr/bin/g++
export CFLAGS=''
export CPPFLAGS=''
export CXXFLAGS=''
export LDFLAGS=''
```

Note: There is a difference between unset env var, and set-as-empty env var.  I had build bugs with Python packages when my `*FLAGS` env vars were unset.  (Calling `gcc` with option `-xO2` was the cause.)  Setting as empty did the trick.